# How to sum all particular attribute values in xml using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0

I have this xml:

```
<AvailRequestSegment>
    <RateRange CurrencyCode="INR" MinRate="0"/>
            <RoomStayCandidates>
                <RoomStayCandidate Quantity="1" RPH="1">
                    <GuestCounts IsPerRoom="true">
                        <GuestCount AgeQualifyingCode="10" Count="2"/>
                    </GuestCounts>
                </RoomStayCandidate>

                <RoomStayCandidate Quantity="1" RPH="2">
                    <GuestCounts IsPerRoom="true">
                        <GuestCount AgeQualifyingCode="10" Count="2"/>
                        <GuestCount Age="10" AgeQualifyingCode="8" Count="1"/>
                        <GuestCount AgeQualifyingCode="7" Count="1"/>
                    </GuestCounts>
                </RoomStayCandidate>

                <RoomStayCandidate Quantity="1" RPH="3">
                    <GuestCounts IsPerRoom="true">
                        <GuestCount AgeQualifyingCode="10" Count="1"/>
                    </GuestCounts>
                </RoomStayCandidate>
            </RoomStayCandidates>
</AvailRequestSegment>
```

I want to convert to this xml format using xsl
*condition-1: `if AgeQualifyingCode="10"`, it's adult, calculate sum of count.

*condition-2: `if AgeQualifyingCode="8" || if AgeQualifyingCode="7"`, it's childred, calculate sum of count.

```
    <occupancies>
        <occupancy rooms="3" adults="5" children="2">
            <paxes>
                <pax type="AD"/>
                <pax type="AD"/>
                <pax type="CH" age="8"/>
                <pax type="CH" age="12"/>
            </paxes>
        </occupancy>
    </occupancies>
```

Comment: So where exactly are you stuck with this?

Comment: while calculating the count attribute in GuestCount node where AgeQualifyingCode="10"

Comment: Why don't you post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: i have posted my answer and  i got the adult count. Pls verify if the steps are wrong

Comment: Your answer is incorrect, and the result is 5 by coincidence only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following expression, evaluated from the context of `AvailRequestSegment`:

```
sum(RoomStayCandidates/RoomStayCandidate/GuestCounts/GuestCount[@AgeQualifyingCode='10']/@Count)
```

will return 5 in the given example.

---

To count the children, change the predicate to :

```
[@AgeQualifyingCode='7' or @AgeQualifyingCode='8']
```

Comment: Thanks for  precise answer,

Comment: One more question . As the age is not given ,I want to assume if   AgeQualifyingCode='7'  Age is between 1-2  and if AgeQualifyingCode='8' Age should be between 2-14.   So how can I write   <pax type="CH" age="2"/> <pax type="CH" age="12"/> as mentioned in the xml

Comment: Don't ask follow-up questions in comments. Ask a new question.